# Where to get server market shares?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

wanted to find out how popular the different Windows Server versions are, can't seem to find anywhere online that tells me. Tried the NetCraft website, but they have old data (from Jan 2011) and they get their results from SSL-enabled servers only, which isn't really a fair representation of all servers on the website.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NPD Group](http://www.npd.com) and [IDC](http://www.idc.com/) are options based on distribution and sales data.  That said, this is pretty far off-topic and I am flagging it as such for removal.  Sorry!

Comment: Or Gartner Group.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies, sorry, didn't know where else to post it on StackExchange.